# afterScriptsLoaded Only Working Once and Not For Tabs

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components, jquery

I am using afterScriptsLoaded to call a function after my jquery has loaded. I have multiple tabs that load charts. On the first pass, each tab is loaded lazy and the charts show up nice. On any other pass through the tabs, nothing shows up. I believe this has to do with the afterScriptsLoaded not loading again. Is there a way around this for tabs? 
Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the Tabs standard salesforce Tabs ?

Comment: It is not the standard one

Comment: You should add code so that it can be looked at .

Comment: Looks to me something [like](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/136743/20830)