# Firing a js event on afterScriptsLoaded when tab selected

Tags: lightning-aura-components, static-resources

I have a lightning component (inside another component) that loads chartJs resource and I am using afterScriptsLoaded to manage all de graph presentation logic. It works perfectly except for some cases when it doesn't render the graphs:

1. when other components navigate to its parent component
2. when its parent component tab is selected

I am supposing that afterScriptsLoaded event is called when the page loads the first time. And the other actions like switching tab doesn't reload scripts again.
But I haven't found a workaround for this problem. 
Please someone with ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably want to define a [custom renderer](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_renderers.htm). Use both afterRender and rerender to make sure you respond to the events that will be called in order to render your charts correctly.

Your code would look like:

```
({
    afterRender: function(cmp, helper) {
        this.superAfterRender();
        helper.renderCharts(cmp);
    },
    rerender: function(cmp, helper) {
        this.superRerender();
        helper.renderCharts(cmp);
    }
})
```

And the actual helper method would be called to render the charts. Also make sure you map a controller method to afterScriptsLoaded to render the charts from there, too. This should cover all possible situations.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but the solution I found was actually this: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/173102/lightning-component-caching-reload-render-issue-whilst-using-chartjs