# Display VF Tab In Lightning

Tags: visualforce, lightning

I have a public calendar that I am trying to display as a VisualForce Page in Lightning. The code is very basic but I am getting the error that it is unavailable in Lightning.

I have checked the box to make it available and have added the Tab to my Lightning Apps that I want to use. What could I be missing?

Controller:

```
public with sharing class CH_Public_Calendar_Controller {
public String calendarId {get; set; }
public CH_Public_Calendar_Controller () {
    calendarId = Calendar__c.getValues('PubCalendar').CalendarId__c;
}
```

}

Page:

```
<apex:page controller="CH_Public_Calendar_Controller" action="/00U/c?cType=1&cal_lkid={!calendarId}&md0={!YEAR(TODAY())}&md1={!MONTH(TODAY())-1}">


Please wait...

</apex:page>
```

This does not seem to be something that should be this difficult. Any assistance would help.

Comment: Take a look at this doc https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=creating_events_lex.htm&language=en_US&type=0 one of the constraints i see is "you can’t view public calendars or resource calendars created in Salesforce Classic."

Comment: Any ideas on public calendars for Lightning that are good work arounds?

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/115396/render-fullcalendar-on-a-lightning-component Take a look at the solution here. You should be able to build a calendar component in no time and put it on your lightning pagelayout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the FullCalendar is what I resorted to to complete this task.

[Render fullcalendar on a lightning component](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/115396/render-fullcalendar-on-a-lightning-component)

Comment: did your code work without moment.js in the proposed answer? I couldnt get it to work without including moments.js file, just curious