# How to handle bookings / appointments in Salesforce?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, community

Can someone recommend me a way of how to handle booking / appointments for a custom object for community users?
Essentially, we've got assets that we rent out, and I somehow need to have a booking functionality for renting these assets. Users should be able to book a time/date for when they wish to use this specific assets.

The Calendar itself would be perfect if I could embed that in a lightning component and share it with an entire community - however, it seems very limited in this sense.

Any guidelines / directions I can take?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are interested to buy an already developed solution then you can consider this one: https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B5gfREAR

Answer (score 2):

We've been doing something similar where we schedule a custom object as a resource using https://fullcalendar.io/ (specifically the [Scheduler](https://fullcalendar.io/scheduler) part in our case).

We have a junction object between our custom object and Contact to represent the appointments, and render these on the calendar using this plugin.
See this [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/116885/10538) by Praveen for more information on how to load this plugin and used it in a Lightning Component. You do need some developer skills though.

Edit:
To add calendar items to the calendar, you could try one of the callbacks that fullcalendar provides. We use the [`select`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/select-callback) callback to enable drag-and-drop, but you could use others like dayClick as well of course:

```
select: $A.getCallback(function(start, end, jsEvent, view, resource) {
    // handle your logic to send the data to the server
    helper.handleNewEvent(start, end, resource);
})
```

Comment: Thanks, I've been looking into FullCalendar as well, but I can't find any documentation on how to add bookings through the calendar - all I can get it to do is display things - have you found a way to create appointments directly in it the calendar?

Comment: I've added some example code to the answer @erikvm

Comment: Thanks for your help Folkert, I will explore Scheduler a bit more, it looks promising. How hard would you say it was to implement it and have it being used with a custom object? Ideally, the scheduler would have "Account" as a top category, and then list all its Asset below in that dropdown functionality.

Comment: It wasn't that hard, if you follow the instructions in the above mentioned answer and if you have some experience with Lightning. The hardest part was in figuring out that I needed to use the $A.getCallback() to make it work.

Comment: Thanks, could you show a real life example? Not really sure where to take it from here